# How to move from iTunes book library to iBooks app

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-synchronization, books

On my last mac system I used iTunes for syncing some PDFs and other books to my ipad.
Now on my new MBP with Mavericks and iTunes 11 there is no Books library anymore, but a new iBooks app.

I started to add some files to iBooks on my mac and followed the instructions to sync them to my ipad, but when opening iTunes and clicking the Books sync section, I still see only the old books formerly added to iTunes in the list. No new book from iBooks is being shown, so not synced to iPad.

I even don’t see a way to delete my old content (and move it to iBooks), because there is no library anymore.
Just deleting the Books folder under iTunes Library didn’t work - the Books sync section still shows the old content, although the sync now complains that it can’t find the files. (Deleting Cache files didn't work here)

So how can I actually enable iBooks app content sync from Mac to iPad and get rid of my former iTunes books library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed it by re-creating my iTunes library as mentioned here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1451.

After moving the `.itl` file I also moved the `Books` folder under `iTunes Music`.

It takes quite some time to import, depending on the size of the library, and it will finally warn that some items could not be found - which is obvious after deleting `Books`.

After that the contents of iBooks appeared in the Books sync tab.

Edit: Unfortunately, all my apps for my i-devices were gone, too. I had to manually transmit them device by device via the menu item `File>Devices>Transfer Purchases from (device name)`. This step is clearing all the apps that I haven't synched to any of the devices at this time, which might be good or bad. However, I can download them again if I'm in the need for that.